# Is it possible to shoot from a corner so that the ball directly goes into the goal without being hit by other players?

Tags: football, technique

Is it possible that one shoots from a corner and the ball directly goes into the goal without being hit by other players?

Has this situation occurred in an actual game (I mean not in training)?

Comment: Here's another example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRL9Kx5yw8E

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has linked this before - [Scoring a goal direct from a corner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_kick#Scoring_a_goal_direct_from_a_corner) - A section on the wikipedia article on Corner kicks.

Comment: Here in Brazil we call it “Olympic goal”.
Olympic goal – A goal scored direct from the corner arc. http://www.englishexperts.com.br/forum/como-dizer-gol-olimpico-em-ingles-t25655.html
Bye!

Comment: Since Wikipedia articles can change, I'll add also a link to the [current revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Corner_kick&oldid=560443336#Scoring_a_goal_direct_from_a_corner) of that article.

Comment: As a ref at regional level in France, I've seen this twice last season... But the second one was scored with the help of a lot of wind !

Comment: Riquelme was an expert at this and made several attempts to do so at the 2006 world cup. Players with enough technical skill are able to bend the ball enough to send it in the top corner

Comment: A corner-kick has exactly the same status as a free-kick, as concerns what one can do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to score a goal directly from a corner.

It has happened many times in [professional leagues across the world](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bn71IqxE5A4) as well as in [international games](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYN0fBYR0Qw).

This type of goal also has a specific name, being an [Olympic Goal](https://www.fifa.com/news/y=2011/m=11/news=getting-grips-with-the-gol-olimpico-1537608.html).

Comment: Are there any notable examples you would like to address?

Comment: Roberto Baggio, David Beckham, and Thierry Henry have all done it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRL9Kx5yw8E

Answer (score 12):

A small addition to the answer provided by @Orangecrush:

It certainly happens from time to time, but it would be a strong overstatement to say it's common. Goals from corners are usually due to extreme spin on the ball, external conditions (e.g. strong wind) or a blunder by the goalkeeper; more often than not a combination of these factors.

While it definitely takes great skill to score from a corner, it's hardly a smart or reliable way to take a corner, as in 9/10 cases it's an easy high ball for the goalie. What's different with Beckham's goal (first example by @Orangecrush) is that it's supposed to be a fast, low cross to the first post which is then hopefully tipped in by a teammate, or an unlucky defender. The fact that it goes in without touching anyone is just the irony of football, well and partially incompetence by both the defenders and the attackers :)

Hope it helps clear up the concept

Comment: This is a good addition. The only time I can remember seeing this is when I was a referee in an amateur match. With club-assistants you tend to choose the goal-line as your position and this one was blown back by the wind into the goal at the far post. There was a strong wind across the length of the field and from my position I could clearly see that it was probably going to enter the goal as the ball was travelling towards me and I was on the far side, players were closer to the ball and could not see this as well as I could. It was definitely not the intention to be a direct goal.